# Página não encontrada Erro 404, [Route("Categorias/list/{page=1}")] no Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, route, http-status-404

Olá, estou com um problema referente a configuração do Route no Asp.Net MVC. O problema e que eu criei uma página de teste onde nesta página estou tentando configurar os recursos de rota. Montei uma pagina com pesquisa com um método para cria um url com o parâmetro da pesquisa.

**Ex:**

> http://localhost:59180/catetorias/list/1

O número **"1"** é o parâmetro que esta sendo passado, e da **PadedList** que crie. E pesquisa funciona perfeitamente e ela consegue altera a url no Chrome, mais quando eu copie a url e colo no Microsoft Edge aparece um página de erro 404, página não encontrada.

**Controller: CategoriasController.cs**

```
using PartionView.DAO;
using PartionView.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using PagedList;

namespace PartionView.Controllers
{

    public class CategoriasController : Controller
    {
        #region Carregamentos de páginas


        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            listCat();
            listUsers();
            return View();
        }

        /*
            O Endereço ficará:
            Get - categorias/list/{page}
        */
        [Route("Catetorias/list/{page=1}")]//Para acessar a função
        public ActionResult pagteste(int page = 1, int pageSize = 4)
        {
            listCatPg("", page, pageSize);
            return View();
        }

        [Route("Categorias/list/{pesquisa=}/{page=1}/{pageSize=4}")]
        public ActionResult pagteste(string pesquisa = "", int page = 1, int pageSize = 4)
        {
            listCatPg(pesquisa, page, pageSize);
            return View();
        }
        #endregion

        //===================================================================================

        #region Metodos Usados
        /// <summary>
        /// Método usado para lista todas as categórias.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Pesquisa">Recebe a categoria para pesquisa.</param>
        /// <returns>Retorna lista na ViewBag de categorias.</returns>
        public ActionResult listCat(string Pesquisa = "")
        {
            var dao = new CategoriaDao();

            var list = dao.listaCategoria(Pesquisa);

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return PartialView("_PvCategorias", list);

            }

            ViewBag.cat = list;

            return View();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Método usado para lista todas as categórias.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Pesquisa">Recebe a categoria para pesquisa.</param>
        /// <returns>Retorna lista na ViewBag de categorias.</returns>
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult listCatPg(string pesquisa = "", int page = 1, int pageSize = 4)
        {
            var dao = new CategoriaDao();

            var list = dao.listaCategoria(pesquisa);


            PagedList<Categoria> pl = new PagedList<Categoria>(list, page, pageSize);

            PesquisaFiltro pf = new PesquisaFiltro
            {
                categorias = pl,
                pesquisa = pesquisa,
                page = page,
                pageSize = pageSize
            };

            ViewBag.pf = pf;

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {                
                return PartialView("_PvPagteste", pf);
            }

            ViewBag.cat = pf;

            return View(pf);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Método usado para lista todas as usuários.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Pesquisa">Recebe a usuário para pesquisa.</param>
        /// <returns>Retorna lista na ViewBag de usuários.</returns>
        public ActionResult listUsers(string PesquisaUsers = "")
        {
            var dao = new CategoriaDao();

            var list = dao.listaUsuarios(PesquisaUsers);            

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return PartialView("_PvUsuarios", list);
            }

            ViewBag.us = list;

            return View();
        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

No RoutConfig.cs e a padrão, só adicionei **MapMvcAttributeRoutes()**.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        //Para mapear os atributos das rotas direto no controller.
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**Coisas que eu percebi fazendo testes:**

1. Se você roda a página index, e colo a url "http://localhost:59180/catetorias/list/1" já passando o parâmetro 1, 2 ou 3 ele não funciona.
2. Não funciona também se você copia a url acima e cola em outro navegador.

Se alguém souber seria de uma boa ajuda.

Answer (score -1):

Já descobri, foi só um erro de digitação:

```
[Route("Catetorias/list/{page=1}")]
```